# How to use boto3 cloudwatch for SageMaker submitted training jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I have submitted a few training jobs from AWS SageMaker. I want to use boto3 cloudwatch api to fetch the cloudwatch data to be displayed within jupyter notebook instead of using CloudWatch UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudWatch GetMetricWidgetImage API to get the graph into the notebook.

Here's an example:

```
import boto3
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

widget = '''{
    "metrics": [
        [ "namespace", "metricname", "dim1", "value1", "dim2", "value2", "dim3", "value3", { "stat": "Average", "id": "m0r0" } ]
    ],
    "title": "Title of the graph",
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "width": 600,
    "height": 400,
    "start": "-PT3H",
    "end": "P0D"
}'''

client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response = client.get_metric_widget_image(
    MetricWidget=widget
)

Image.open(BytesIO(response['MetricWidgetImage']))
```

You can get the widget definition by opening the metric you need in CloudWatch Console, clicking on the `Source` tab and selecting `Image API` view on the bottom. Tweak the width and height per your liking.

You will also need to adjust the policy on your SageMaker execution role to allow calls to GetMetricWidgetImage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was wondering. don't we need the title of the training job to be passed when we call get_metric_widget_image function?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. You want to get sage maker graphs, like the ones described on the bottom of this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/training-metrics.html inside the jupyter notebook?If yes, you can either go to CloudWatch and copy the full widget definition, as described in the answer, or you can try to construct the widget dynamically, which would entail knowing the training job name for example.